# Read UInt32 from InputStream

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, inputstream, endianness

I need to communicate with a server that has a special message format: Each message begins with 4 bytes (together a unsigned long / UInt32 in big endian format) which determines the length of the following message. After those 4 bytes the message is sent as a normal string

So I first need to read 4 bytes into an Integer (32 bit unsigned). In Java I do this like:

```
DataInputStream is;
...
int len = is.readInt();
```

How can I do this in Swift 4?

At the moment I use

```
var lengthbuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
let bytecount = istr.read(&lengthbuffer, maxLength: 4)
let lengthbytes = lengthbuffer[0...3]
let bigEndianValue = lengthbytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
            ($0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt32.self, capacity: 1) { $0 })
            }.pointee
let bytes_expected = Int(UInt32(bigEndian: bigEndianValue))
```

But this looks not like this is the most elegant way. And furthermore, sometimes (I cannot reproduces it reliably) there is a wrong value read (too big). When I then try to allocate memory for the following message, the app crashes:

```
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bytes_expected)
let bytes_read = istr.read(buffer, maxLength: bytes_expected)
```

So what is the swift way to read a UInt32 from a InputStream?

---

EDIT:

My current code (implemented things from the comments. Thanks!) looks like this:

```
private let inputStreamAccessQueue  = DispatchQueue(label: "SynchronizedInputStreamAccess")  // NOT concurrent!!!

// This is called on Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
func handleInput() {
    self.inputStreamAccessQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {            
        guard let istr = self.inputStream, istr.hasBytesAvailable else {
            log.error(self.buildLogMessage("handleInput() called when inputstream has no bytes available"))
            return
        }

        let lengthbuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 4)
        defer { lengthbuffer.deallocate(capacity: 4) }
        let lenbytes_read = istr.read(lengthbuffer, maxLength: 4)

        guard lenbytes_read == 4 else {
            self.errorHandler(NetworkingError.InputError("Input Stream received \(lenbytes_read) (!=4) bytes"))
            return
        }

        let bytes_expected = Int(UnsafeRawPointer(lengthbuffer).load(as: UInt32.self).bigEndian)
        log.info(self.buildLogMessage("expect \(bytes_expected) bytes"))

        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bytes_expected)
        let bytes_read = istr.read(buffer, maxLength: bytes_expected)
        guard bytes_read == bytes_expected else {
            print("Error: Expected \(bytes_expected) bytes, read \(bytes_read)")
            return
        }

        guard let message = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: bytes_expected, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: true) else {
            log.error("ERROR WHEN READING")
            return
        }

        self.handleMessage(message)
    }
}
```

This works most of the time, but sometimes istr.read() does not read bytes_expected bytes but bytes_read < bytes_expected. This results in another hasbytesAvailable event and handleInput() is called again. This time, of course, the first 4 bytes that are read do not contain the length of a new message but some content of the last message. But my code does not know that, so the first bytes are interpreted as the length. In many cases this is a real big value => allocating too much memory => crash

I think this is the explanation for the bug. But how to solve it?
Call read() on the stream while hasBytesAvailable = true? Is there maybe a better solution?

I would assume that when I loop, the hasBytesAvailableEvent would still happen after every read() => handleInput would still be called again too early... How can I avoid this?

---

EDIT 2: I have implemented the loop now, unfortunately it is still crashing with the same error (and probably same reason). Relevant code:

```
let bytes_expected = Int(UnsafeRawPointer(lengthbuffer).load(as: UInt32.self).bigEndian)

var message = ""
var bytes_missing = bytes_expected
while bytes_missing > 0 {
    print("missing", bytes_missing)
    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bytes_missing)
    let bytes_read = istr.read(buffer, maxLength: bytes_missing)

    guard bytes_read > 0 else {
        print("bytes_read not <= 0: \(bytes_read)")
        return
    }

    guard bytes_read <= bytes_missing else {
        print("Read more bytes than expected. missing=\(bytes_missing), read=\(bytes_read)")
        return
    }

    guard let partial_message = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: bytes_expected, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: true) else {
        log.error("ERROR WHEN READING")
        return
    }

    message = message + partial_message
    bytes_missing -= bytes_read
}
```

My console output when it crashes:

> missing 1952807028 malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1952808960) failed
>   (error code=3)
>   *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

So it seems that the whole handleInput() method is called too early, although I use the barrier! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is a bit too complicated, but I cannot spot an obvious error. Therefore it would be helpful to know about a concrete problem. What "wrong value" do you get for which data?

Comment: Sometimes (not reproducible for me as I do not have access to the server code) bytes_expected contains very big values, e.g. 194394543565 and then the app crashes because that much memory cannot be allocated.
I do not expect such large values. Normally my messages are < 5000 bytes and the server sends the correct length (other clients work, only my iOS client crashes sometimes)

Comment: The only explanation I have is that maybe two calls to istr.read are "overlapping", such that the second call reads 4 bytes somewhere in the middle of a message and interprets it as length. That could be because the first call to read() takes longer as usual. I tried to avoid this by wrapping the message reading into self.inputStreamAccessQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) { ... }

where 
private let inputStreamAccessQueue  = DispatchQueue(label: "SynchronizedInputStreamAccess")  // NOT concurrent!!!

If I am right, this should avoid that the stream is accessed concurrently.

Comment: It crashed again. bytes_expected contains 1886348902
The console says 
----
malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1886351360) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
----
and there is this error shown: "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)"
in this line:
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bytes_expected)

Comment: Is that because you read wrong data, or because the conversion to UInt32 is wrong? (I assume the former.) You should check the return value from read() if the expected number of bytes was actually read (it may be shorter than what you request on communication channels like sockets). You could also dump the 4 raw length bytes.

Comment: I think the assumption is right.

1. call: bytes_expected = 5146 => Error: Expected 5146 bytes, read 2732
----------
2. call: bytes_expected = 1952807028 => crash.

So it seems that read() does not read the full message at one time. But why? Does this depend on my network connection or are there some other limits? 


How can I dump the raw length bytes? I tried print(lengthbuffer) and print(lengthbuffer.pointee)

Comment: I edited my question and added the full current code

Comment: Seems to me you should build some kind of state machine to distinguish the different states the code can be in (waiting for/reading length bytes, waiting for/reading payload, etc.). But that's really a totally different question. If you want help debugging this, I suggest you a) open another question and b) provide a reproducible failing test case so others can check what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! My new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340728/read-exactly-n-bytes-from-inputstream-in-swift-4

Don't wonder about the new user name. This one is the right, the other will be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I‘d do it like this (ready to be pasted into a playground):

```
import Foundation

var stream = InputStream(data: Data([0,1,0,0]))
stream.open()
defer { stream.close() }

var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 4)
defer { buffer.deallocate(capacity: 4) }
guard stream.read(buffer, maxLength: 4) >= 4 else {
    // handle all cases: end of stream, error, waiting for more data to arrive...
    fatalError()
}
let number = UnsafeRawPointer(buffer).load(as: UInt32.self)
number // 256
number.littleEndian // 256
number.bigEndian // 65536
```

Using `UnsafeRawPointer.load` directly (without explicit rebinding) is safe for trivial types [according to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer). Trivial types are generally those that don‘t require ARC operations.

> Alternatively, you can access the same memory as a different type without rebinding through untyped memory access, so long as the bound type and the destination type are trivial types.

Comment: Thanks, this is an elegant solution! Also I didn't know about defer but this seems to be very useful :)

Reading the UInt32 from the input stream works now. But the crashes still occur and I think I found the reason. Sometimes (this happens only for "long" messages, e.g. 5000 bytes) the length is read correctly and stored into bytes_expected. Then I call istr.read(maxLength: bytes_expected) but this does not return the amount of bytes that I expected (but, lets say only 2000). So I only read the first part of the message and then return.

Comment: The next time I read bytes_expected from the stream I get the rest of the last message and interpret this as the length of the next message (resulting in very big bytes_expected values) and this causes my app to crash.

So I see two possible solutions:

1) Find a method that does not read MAXlength bytes but EXACTlength bytes. Does such a method exist?
2) Do a loop that reads the stream until exactly bytes_expected bytes are read.

Comment: Yes, you need to use a loop. That‘s why the method is named read(_:maxLength:) and not read(_:length:). This is a very common pattern with stream APIs. The stream only has a limited buffer internally so if you ask it for more bytes than it has available, it will return a smaller number. This also applies to smaller reads like we do here, so you should even use a loop to read the 4 length bytes to be sure.

Comment: How can I avoid that the InputStream.hasBytesAvailable event is called after every read()? If I cannot avoid this, then I think the loop solution would still not work because other calls could be handled first. I'm not sure if my barrier helps here...

Comment: I also edited my question and added my full current code

Comment: Unfortunately it still crashes when I loop until I have read the amount of bytes I expected... See edit 2 of my question

Comment: More debugging showed that my assumption was right :( The barrier does not work. There are multiple calls of handleInput at the same time and this causes the wrong bytes_expected value...
Do you have an idea how I can avoid this?

Comment: Hi, I will try it but I'm not sure if this will be the correct solution. Because the protocol specification says that there will always be exactly 4 bytes indicating the message length

Do you think there is a problem with my barrier?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `load(as:)` to convert the buffer to the `UInt32`, and I would make sure you make the endianness explicit, e.g.

```swift
let value = try stream.read(type: UInt32.self, endianness: .little)
```

Where:

```swift
enum InputStreamError: Error {
    case readFailure
}

enum Endianness {
    case little
    case big
}

extension InputStream {
    func read<T: FixedWidthInteger>(type: T.Type, endianness: Endianness = .little) throws -> T {
        let size = MemoryLayout<T>.size
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: size)
        let count = read(&buffer, maxLength: size)
        guard count == size else {
            throw InputStreamError.readFailure
        }

        return buffer.withUnsafeBytes { pointer -> T in
            switch endianness {
            case .little: return T(littleEndian: pointer.load(as: T.self))
            case .big:    return T(bigEndian: pointer.load(as: T.self))
            }
        }
    }

    func readFloat(endianness: Endianness) throws -> Float {
        return try Float(bitPattern: read(type: UInt32.self, with: endianness))
    }

    func readDouble(endianness: Endianness) throws -> Double {
        return try Double(bitPattern: read(type: UInt64.self, with: endianness))
    }
}
```

Note, I made `read(type:endianness:)` a generic, so it can be reused with any of the standard integer types. I have also thrown in `readFloat` and `readDouble` for good measure.