# Read exactly n bytes from InputStream in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, tcp, network-programming, inputstream

I have a server that sends me messages over TCP where the first 4 bytes determine the length of the rest of the message. So I need to

1) read 4 bytes into an UInt32 (works) and store it into *bytes_expected*

2) read *bytes_expected* bytes into *message*

Right now my code looks like this:

```
private let inputStreamAccessQueue  = DispatchQueue(label: "SynchronizedInputStreamAccess")
```

---

```
func inputStreamHandler(_ event: Stream.Event) {
    switch event {
        case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
            self.handleInput()

        ...
    }
}
```

---

```
func handleInput() {
    // **QUESTION: Do I use this barrier wrong?**
    self.inputStreamAccessQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {            
        guard let istr = self.inputStream else {
            log.error(self.buildLogMessage("InputStream is nil"))
            return
        }

        guard istr.hasBytesAvailable else {
            log.error(self.buildLogMessage("handleInput() called when inputstream has no bytes available"))
            return
        }

        let lengthbuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 4)
        defer { lengthbuffer.deallocate(capacity: 4) }
        let lenbytes_read = istr.read(lengthbuffer, maxLength: 4)

        guard lenbytes_read == 4 else {
            self.errorHandler(NetworkingError.InputError("Input Stream received \(lenbytes_read) (!=4) bytes"))
            return
        }

        let bytes_expected = Int(UnsafeRawPointer(lengthbuffer).load(as: UInt32.self).bigEndian)
        log.info(self.buildLogMessage("expect \(bytes_expected) bytes"))

        print("::DEBUG", call, "bytes_expected", bytes_expected)

        var message = ""
        var bytes_missing = bytes_expected
        while bytes_missing > 0 {
            //print("::DEBUG", call, "bytes_missing", bytes_missing)
            let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bytes_missing)
            let bytes_read = istr.read(buffer, maxLength: bytes_missing)

            print("::DEBUG", call, "bytes_read", bytes_read)

            guard bytes_read > 0 else {
                print("bytes_read not > 0: \(bytes_read)")
                return
            }

            guard bytes_read <= bytes_missing else {
                print("Read more bytes than expected. missing=\(bytes_missing), read=\(bytes_read)")
                return
            }

            guard let partial_message = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: bytes_read, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: true) else {
                log.error("ERROR WHEN READING")
                return
            }

            message = message + partial_message
            bytes_missing -= bytes_read
        }

        self.handleMessage(message)
    }
}
```

My problem is that istr.read(buffer, maxLength: bytes_missing) sometimes does not read all messages at once, so I loop until I have read all I want. But I still see my app crashing (rarely) because handleInput() is called again while another call to that method is still running. In this case, bytes_expected contains random values and the app crashes due to illegal memory allocation.

I thought I could avoid this by using the barrier. But it seems this does not work... Am I using the barrier wrong?

Comment: Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48309099/read-uint32-from-inputstream ?

Comment: Yes, but one guy in the comments told me to open a new question. And I accidentally used an old account for the last question. I deleted the old account and will use this one in future

Comment: Yes, a new question is the right thing here, I just wondered about the different user name.

Comment: I do not have the time to write a full answer, but my suggestion it *not* to fight against the asynchronous nature of network IO, and *not* to use a barrier. – In `handleInput()` just collect the available data in a buffer. If the buffer contains enough data (4 bytes for the counter + the number of expected bytes), process it and remove it from the buffer. Otherwise do nothing and wait for more data.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea (and should be easy to implement). I just wonder why no tutorial / documentation mentions these kind of problems and how to solve them. I also could not find many related questions. Is everyone else using some library that handles all for them? If so, could you recommend one? There might be a change in the server that requires me to use SSL in the future. It seems BlueSocket (https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket) can handle this. Do you know this lib and would you recommend it to me or are there better ones?

Comment: I have no experience with that library and no recommendations, sorry.

Comment: Do you maybe know other libraries?

I mean, this is such a common task and there is NO full working example anywhere on the internet. Implementing this yourself can work but is very prone to errors. I suppose I will also have to implement the same for sending messages, right? Because the write method also does not always send everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is not to fight against the asynchronous nature of network I/O.
Read and collect data in a buffer whenever the `Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable` event
is signalled. If the buffer contains enough data (4 length bytes plus the
expected message length) then process the data and remove it. Otherwise do nothing
and wait for more data.

The following (untested) code is meant as a demonstration.
It shows only the parts which are relevant for this particular problem.
Initialization, event handler, etc are omitted for brevity.

```
class MessageReader {

    var buffer = Data(count: 1024) // Must be large enough for largest message + 4
    var bytesRead = 0 // Number of bytes read so far

    // Called from `handleInput` with a complete message.
    func processMessage(message: Data) {
        // ...
    }

    // Called from event handler if `Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable` is signalled.
    func handleInput(istr: InputStream) {
        assert(bytesRead < buffer.count)

        // Read from input stream, appending to previously read data:
        let maxRead = buffer.count - bytesRead
        let amount = buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (p: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in
            istr.read(p + bytesRead, maxLength: maxRead)
        }
        guard amount > 0 else {
            // handle EOF or read error ...
            fatalError()
        }
        bytesRead += amount

        while bytesRead >= 4 {
            // Read message size:
            let messageSize = buffer.withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafePointer<UInt32>) in
                Int(UInt32(bigEndian: p.pointee))
            }
            let totalSize = 4 + messageSize
            guard totalSize <= buffer.count else {
                // Handle buffer too small for message situation ...
                fatalError()
            }

            if bytesRead < totalSize {
                break // Not enough data to read message.
            }

            // Buffer contains complete message now. Process it ...
            processMessage(message: buffer[4 ..< totalSize])

            // ... and remove it from the buffer:
            if totalSize < bytesRead {
                // Move remaining data to the front:
                buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (p: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in
                    _ = memmove(p, p + totalSize, bytesRead - totalSize)
                }
            }
            bytesRead -= totalSize
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this if I don't find a working lib

Comment: I get the error "simultaneous accesses to 0x16584fe0, but modification requires exclusive access." in the line where I read into the buffer: istr.read(p + bytesRead, maxLength: buffer.count - bytesRead)

It seems this is a new feature in Swift 4... How can I avoid this?

Comment: @ITStudent: The Swift runtime complains because `buffer.count` is read while mutating `buffer`. Can be avoided by computing the maxLength beforehand.

Comment: Seems to work (I modified your idea but it still helped a lot!)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48360431/3827381

Comment: "My suggestion is not to fight against the asynchronous nature of network I/O."  This is just the wisdom that I needed.  Thank, you.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Martin R (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344040/3827381 - Thank you very much!) I came up with this solution:

```
var buffer = Data(count: 4096)
var offset = 0 // the index of the first byte that can be overridden
var readState = 0
var missingMsgBytes = 0
var msg = ""

func handleInput(_ istr: InputStream) {
    assert(buffer.count >= 5, "buffer must be large enough to contain length info (4 bytes) and at least one payload byte => min 5 bytes buffer required")
    assert(offset < buffer.count, "offset \(offset) is not smaller than \(buffer.count)")

    let toRead = buffer.count - offset
    let read = buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (p: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in istr.read(p + offset, maxLength: toRead) }
    guard read > 0 else {
        self.errorHandler(NetworkingError.InputError("Input Stream received \(read) bytes which is smaller than 0 => Network error"))
        return
    }
    offset += read
    var msgStart = 0
    var msgEnd = 0

    if readState == 0 {
        if offset < 4 {
            return
        }
        missingMsgBytes = buffer[0...3].withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafePointer<UInt32>) in Int(UInt32(bigEndian: p.pointee)) }
        msgStart = 4
        msgEnd = offset
        readState = 1
    } else {
        msgStart = 0
        msgEnd = offset
    }

    var fullMessageRead = false

    if readState == 1 {
        let payloadRead = msgEnd - msgStart
        if payloadRead <= missingMsgBytes {
            assert(msgEnd > msgStart, "msgEnd (\(msgEnd) <= msgStart \(msgStart). This should not happen")
            if msgEnd > msgStart {
                msg += String(data: buffer[msgStart..<msgEnd], encoding: .utf8)!
                missingMsgBytes -= payloadRead
                offset = 0
            }
            fullMessageRead = (missingMsgBytes == 0)
        } else { // read more than was missing
            msg += String(data: buffer[msgStart..<msgStart+missingMsgBytes], encoding: .utf8)!
            fullMessageRead = true
            buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (p: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in
                _ = memmove(p, p + missingMsgBytes, read - missingMsgBytes) // dst, src, number
            }
            offset = read-missingMsgBytes
        }
    }

    if fullMessageRead {
        handleMessage(msg)
        readState = 0
         msg = ""
        missingMsgBytes = 0
    }
}
```

This solution is able to read messages of arbitrary size. The buffer size only determines how much can be read at one time => The bigger the buffer, the faster the app.

I tested the code for about an hour now and it did not crash. The old code crashed after 1-2 minutes. It seems to be finally working now.

But as I want to improve my programming knowledge I'd like to ask if there are some unnecessary complicated things in my code or if anyone sees a bug that could possibly still cause the app to crash or to read wrong data?

Comment: I can spot one problem: If a partial message is read and has an incomplete UTF-8 sequence at the end, then `String(data: buffer[msgStart..<msgEnd], encoding: .utf8)!` would crash. – That is not impossible to solve, but cumbersome. (That's why I chose the "simple" approach to store everything in the read buffer until the message is complete.)

Comment: In the moment you wrote this comment, the app crashed in exactly that line. :-D

Comment: So if I want to be able to read messages of arbitrary length I have to manually check if the characters at the end are valid UTF8 and if not, move the end to the left until I only have valid characters? Seems to be tricky and again not very easy to test :(

By the way: What is the best way to test all that networking stuff? At the moment I just run the app and wait for a crash but I think there might be better ways.

Comment: I have another idea. What about starting with a buffer of size n and every time it is to small, increase it so that the size is >= messageLength? I mean, appending the partial message to msg every time should internally work about the same?

Comment: That should work. You can simply set `buffer.count` to a larger value, that appends zero bytes. – You might still want to check against a maximum value, otherwise the system could try to allocate  many GBs if bad data comes in.

Comment: Another question:
I think it would be a good idea to call handleMessage() in another thread (async), right? Which queue would one use for that and which qos?